# Google Places API does not return gym info

Tags: google-places-api

I could not get Google Places API to return gym info. Below is an example request api.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.347075,-111.96318&radius=100&types=gym&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBg8HI6sH1Rxyhn1Mno_hhgDawuF1KAfq0
```

([Open URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.347075,-111.96318&radius=100&types=gym&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBg8HI6sH1Rxyhn1Mno_hhgDawuF1KAfq0))

I know the lat/lon in the link is valid.

If I remove the "types=gym" (see below link" it returns some places info but none of type gym.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.347075,-111.96318&radius=100&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBg8HI6sH1Rxyhn1Mno_hhgDawuF1KAfq0
```

([Open URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.347075,-111.96318&radius=100&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBg8HI6sH1Rxyhn1Mno_hhgDawuF1KAfq0))

Is there a limitation on the api?
Also, could I have the api to return an uri which takes me directly to the location?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to increase your search radius a bit - you're looking for results within a 100m circle. Try this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.347075,-111.96318&radius=200&types=gym&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBg8HI6sH1Rxyhn1Mno_hhgDawuF1KAfq0

Increasing the radius to just 200m returns a result; at 1000m you get four results.

You can then pass the `reference` value to a Places Details search to get the `url` value, as follows:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CnRnAAAA99xxsFT0V-FNigzMi7GEnmkqWRYCOZG-lrQH0fpw9iI_JUp5WHrYOCcTGpeyzVdHrtk3rE2zrHleBxRw4i67K0sT_fhsSQufaAHN80Oi4OvxR-amG_W4plz5Mr8a-512584oHpfUpV87jMqyF2R8cRIQpqTgOCgZtZF0hYR4R_ZVRRoUEIS-oN1fcyVQcN5nj7DxaNK-e8o&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBg8HI6sH1Rxyhn1Mno_hhgDawuF1KAfq0

The `url` links to the Google Maps Place page: http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=2681829493569576902

See the docs here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceDetailsRequests

Answer (score 0):

also there is a limit of the no. requests on this particular api.
2500 IIRC -- but you can read it in the docs

Comment: Thanks for the note, but I think it would be more relevant to add this as a comment to original post.

Comment: @Shervin: OP asks: "Is there a limitation on the api?"

Comment: It also has a practical problem at hand which request number limitation might or might not be part of it.

Answer (score -1):

Are there 20 coming back with the "types=gym" call? If so then you are hitting the limitation of the api and it just so happens the [20 returned](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchResponses) are not a gym:

> The Places API returns up to 20 establishment results. Additionally,
>   political results may be returned which serve to identify the area of
>   the request